# pip uninstall GDAL gives AttributeError: 'PathMetadata' object has no attribute 'isdir'

Tags: python, pip, gdal

I'm trying to `pip install geopandas` as a fresh installation, so I want to remove existing packages like `GDAL` and `fiona`. I've already managed to `pip uninstall fiona`, but when I try to uninstall or reinstall `GDAL` it gives the following error message:

```
(base) C:\usr>pip install C:/usr/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/GDAL-3.4.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\usr\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gdal-3.4.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: GDAL
  Attempting uninstall: GDAL
    Found existing installation: GDAL 3.0.2
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 405, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 68, in install_given_reqs
    uninstalled_pathset = requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "C:\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 637, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset = UninstallPathSet.from_dist(dist)
  File "C:\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 554, in from_dist
    for script in dist.iterdir("scripts"):
  File "C:\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\metadata\pkg_resources.py", line 156, in iterdir
    if not self._dist.isdir(name):
  File "C:\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2816, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._provider, attr)
AttributeError: 'PathMetadata' object has no attribute 'isdir'
```

Does anyone know why `GDAL` cannot be uninstalled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just came across this question after getting the same error.  Coincidentally I had just upgraded pip (I was getting tired of the yellow warnings).

All I had was to down grade my pip

```
pip install pip==21.3.1 --user
```

Comment: same solution here, for gdal 3.4.1 and conda 4.12.0 on win10.

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing the same `AttributeError` as you when trying to install `google-cloud-firestore`.  My solution was to upgrade my version of pip.  In my case, I upgraded to pip from 22.0.2 to 22.3.1

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```